# Why does the variable not show in Bash?

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# = 3 ] 
then 
  echo "input num=3"
  op=$2
  op_a=$1
  op_b=$3
  if [ $op  =  "add" ]
  then
        c= expr $op_a + $op_b   
        echo  "$op_a + $op_b = $c"  

    elif [ $op  =  "sub" ]
    then    
        c= expr $op_a - $op_b   
        echo  "$op_a - $op_b = $c"  

    elif [ $op  =  "mul" ]
    then    
        c= expr $op_a \* $op_b  
        echo  "$op_a * $op_b = $c"  

    elif [ $op  =  "div" ]
    then    
        c= expr $op_a / $op_b   
        echo  "$op_a / $op_b = $c"

    else
        echo "Unknow op"
    fi   
else 
  echo "input num error"
fi
```

After running this shell, `$c`(the variable) does not show in Bash's enco.

Could anyone tell me the reason?
The expr maybe has conflict with echo, or my config has some problem?

Thanks a lot
P.S the Linux version is Ubuntu 16.04 and the bash version is 4.3.42.

Comment: You aren't assigning a value to `c`. Please use shellcheck.net on your code first.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a scope problem.  Your script starts its own instance of the bash shell, and $c has value there.  When the script is done, its operating environment/context of execution//whatever is over and done, so your $c variable no longer exists.

However, if you use source to load your script, it is run as part of your current shell, so $c will still have value.

```
#!/bin/bash

c="Hello World"

echo $c
```

echo $c gives null.

```
user@host:~ $ ./demo.sh
Hello World

user@host:~ $ echo $c

user@host:~ $ source demo.sh
Hello World

user@host:~ $ echo $c
Hello World
```

Comment: Maybe I could describe the question more clear?When i  input ./demo.sh 2 add 3 in the terminal,the terminal only showed the $c variable in the expr statements,and the echo statements showed the $op_a's value and $op_b's values.Or the question is how could i echo the statement as "2 + 3 =5"?Thank you for your answer sincerely.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a scope problem. The script is called with 3 args, and then attempts to print results with different operators. The actual problem is the expr invocations.

Comment: After reading your answer and Jens's answer,I know what i did wrong,thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

These

```
c= expr $op_a - $op_b
```

don't do what you want. (This assigns the empty value to `c`, then runs `expr` ignoring the result.) You need command substitution:

```
c=$(expr $op_a - $op_b)
```

Comment: Ok,i know what your mean,and i solve my question.Thank you!

Comment: @Ang.lee Good! The way to express this on Stackoverflow is to upvote the answer and accept it by clicking the green arrow to the left.